# Toggle music in unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, toggle

Currently I have my toggle to On Value Change make AudioSource.enabled, which does turn the music off.

However when I die in the game the level gets reloaded causing the toggle to go back to its default state and then i am unable to turn the music back on.

So what is the best way to make a music toggle and have the state of the toggle be remembered on load?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be a singleton music manager game object that is created only once and is persistent between scenes, meaning that it will not be destroyed when you reload a scene or load a different scene.

You can read more about Singleton patterns here: http://unitypatterns.com/singletons/

Comment: I'm fairly new to design patterns and this solution feels just right. Besides, why not :P ?

Comment: My comment wasn't specific to your answer(If I'd consider wrong it, I usually downvote explaining why). It's a just a personal disappointment because of hearing too much suggestion of using singletons.. singletons are often bad for several reasons, just google for some considerations on the topic or start from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons .

Answer (score 0):

You can save persistent data across scenes using [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html). Just store there the audio status and be sure to check if it's enabled when loading a new scene (for example inside `Awake` method of a `MonoBehaviour` attached on the same `AudioSource`'s `GameObject`).

Side note

Depending on the specific situations, turn off globally the volume could be easier using [AudioListener.volume](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioListener-volume.html) rather than modifying all `AudioSources`.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me how to actually store the audio status and how i would get the toggle to stay on or off after reload?